# How to correctly create a zip file that can be uploaded to AWS lambda using Eclipse?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, aws-lambda

**How do I create a zip file from an existing Java project that can be uploaded to an AWS Lambda function??**

I can't find any clear steps on how to do this. I want to export my Eclipse project as a zip file and then upload it to AWS Lambda. Currently, I use the AWS Toolkit in Eclipse to upload the project, but now I want to do it manually using a zip file.

What are the steps?

This is how I tried to do it. This is where I export the project as a zip:

[image: exporting as zip file]

Then, I go to AWS and choose to upload a zip file:

[image: upload type]

I choose my zip file and then test the code and this is the error I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error loading class com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
}
```

[image: errors]

**EDIT**: The function works if I upload using the Toolkit so I know that all resources are in the folder, I just need to figure out how to use it.
And this is the function's code:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler extends IOException implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, String> {

    private static AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).build();

    public LambdaFunctionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(SNSEvent event, Context context) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            return "SUCCESS2";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("caught exception");
        }
        return "FAILURE2";
    }
    


}
```

**EDIT #2**: This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.91</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hierynomus/sshj -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
        <version>0.29.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Maven project in Eclipse and then Export that as a JAR file that you can upload to the AWS Management Console. Its very easy to do so. To learn how to do this use case, see this AWS tutorial. It uses IntelliJ (just switch that for Eclipse), and follow the rest of the doc.

The example use case for this Lambda function is to detect personal protective equipment (PPE) in images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. It steps you through all steps including deploying the Lambda function.

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

You will never encounter issues that you are seeing in this tool when building and deploying via the Console.

**Update**
This Lambda function works -- just tested it. Here are the results in the Lambda Console.

[image]

Data that is placed in the DynamoDB table:

[image]

Your error is saying it cannot find the cred provider. When using Lambda, you do not need to set creds in your Java code. The permissions are set in the IAM role. You need to set the policy for the IAM role so it can invoke the services.  SO in this example use case, we set policies for **lambda-support**.

**Another Update**

From Eclipse, I build a project using your code (I think this PPE is pretty advanced - so we will make a new one named Getting Started with Lambda). It worked well:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. I did exactly as stated in that link. I exported to a .jar. I went to AWS and uploaded said .jar and still the same error.

Comment: When you deploy this JAR file, what are you seeing.  DId you setup your IAM role properly

Comment: What do you mean what am I seeing? I click upload the .zip file or .jar file (I’ve tried both) and then I try testing it and I get an error as shown in my question. I believe my IAM role is set up fine because I am able to upload via the Toolkit. How else can I check that? However I don’t think that is the issue.

Comment: Also, when I deploy, it says it was successful but when I run it is when I get the error. I am doing everything you have mentioned and nothing helps.

Comment: You issue is you are tying to set creds in a Lambda function - private static AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).build()  

You need to set the IAM role as shown in the tutorial - not use creds.

Comment: I will try and do this Lambda function using your code from Eclipse. I am wondering if there is another issue I am not seeing using my IDE.

Comment: That would be super helpful if you could. Why would the credentials cause an error though when it works using the toolkit? Doesn't the code look the same once its uploaded whether its uploaded using the toolkit vs manual upload? id prefer to leave the credentials in the code if possible. this code has been like this for years.

Comment: I will get to the bottom of your issue using Eclipse. I am very curious what is happening.

Comment: I truly truly appreciate this. I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days.

Comment: Contact me via Linked IN  (see my profile) and send me a message. I will setup a meeting with you tomorrow and step you through all of this.

Comment: It says I need linkedin premium to message you but I tried connecting with you. And then I can message you. Thanks a lot!